# How to get pdf file bookmarks using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to get bookmarks from the pdf file using c# .

Which is the best library that do this .

Comment: Not sure about your first question but I suggest [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/index.php). I can do pretty much anything with a PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this code to get all bookmarks from a pdf file using iTextSharp:

```
public void ExportBookmarksToXml(string SourcePdfPath, string xmlOutputPath, string Password = "")
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SourcePdfPath, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(Password));
       //Collection of bookmarks
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            SimpleBookmark.ExportToXML(bookmarks, memoryStream, "ISO8859-1", true);
            //MessageBox.Show(bookmarks[0].Values.ToString());
            File.WriteAllBytes(xmlOutputPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```