# How to get PDF child bookmark with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

i had used the sample code from the thread "How to get pdf file bookmarks using c#".

it works but it can get the first level bookmark only. how can i get the child bookmark ?

thanks

```
   'Read PDF bookmark
    Dim bookmarks As IList(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader)
    Dim i As Integer = 0

If Not IsNothing(bookmarks) Then

For Each bookmark In bookmarks

    pdf_bookmark += bookmarks(i).Values(0).ToString()

    If i < bookmarks.Count - 1 Then
        pdf_bookmark += ", "
    End If

    i = i + 1
Next
```

End If

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get pdf file bookmarks using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829927/how-to-get-pdf-file-bookmarks-using-c-sharp)

Comment: use the code in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829927/how-to-get-pdf-file-bookmarks-using-c-sharp?rq=1) and then use any online free C# to VB.NET converter.

Comment: i had used the code, it works. but it can get the first level bookmark only. how can i get the child bookmark ?